# Rails scaffolding with docker and file ownership

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, docker-compose

I'm experimenting with Ruby on Rails and Docker, following [this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/) tutorial. In *Build the Project* section You can see that Rails scaffold is run with

```
docker-compose run web rails new . --force --database=postgresql --skip-bundle
```

And immediately after, the:

```
 sudo chown -R $USER:$USER .
```

To get access to generated files, because Docker creates them as *root*.

**How can I omit changing the permissions every time?** Let's say I want to create simple migration file using:

```
docker-compose run web rails g migration create_users
```

It seems unpractical to modify the ownership after every simple command like this, but in every tutorial/source I've found noone talks about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've exeprienced the same issue and the main problem for me was `sublime-text` not able to edit the files owned by root. So my solution was to use `sublime-text` as root for I could comfortably edit any project files. To do this execute in your shell:

```
gksu subl
```

That solved my problem. Hope it solved yours.

**UPDATED**

Ok. I found solution which doesn't depend on any Ruby editor or IDE. So what you need is add your current ubuntu user to docker users group for you could run docker commands as its user, not `root`.

First, you may need to add the docker group if it doesn't exist (but it should exist now). In your shell execute

```
sudo groupadd docker
```

**Add your current user to docker group**

```
sudo gpasswd -a ${USER} docker
```

**Restart the docker daemon**

```
sudo service docker restart
```

or

```
sudo service docker.io restart
```

(depends on your system)

**Activate user groups changes.** To do it either perform LOG OUT / LOG IN or in your shell

```
newgrp docker
```

**Then add to the end of your `dockerfile`**

```
USER <your_user_name>
```

or

```
USER <your_user_id>
```

**Now you can execute commands like**

```
docker-compose run web rails g migration SomeMigration
```

without `sudo` but as your current user.

And the files created by that commands will be owned by your current user not `root`.

Comment: I'm using RubyMine, but still, the idea looks good and I didn't thought about it.

Comment: Found and tested on my own project an alternative solution which doesn't depend on any Ruby editor or IDE. Please try it and don't forget to accept my answer if it will help you.